# Use of customized Wix ProgressDlg doesn't trigger install sequence

Tags: wix, installation, progress

I have a strange problem with Wix installer. I can modify the entire InstallUISequence, I can insert custom dialogs and make them work without problems. But then I needed to customize ProgressDlg, so I made a copy of wxs file, changed everything in my code I was avare of. I'm able to show it, but it gets no events, simply because actual install sequence never starts. The only thing I can do then is to cancel it, which works, as Cancel button has its own event published.

When I look to a code of predefined UIs from Wix I can't find any trigger or anything which could help. Could anyone tell me what I made wrong here?

Comment: Can you publish a minimalist sample?  Perhaps in a Git repos.

Comment: Thank you for a reply, but I think that even a minimal example is relatively big. I removed all references to Wix's ProgressDlg from some other dialogs (which I must copy wxs files and make changes there). I think I miss only something to trigger actual installation, but I couldn't find anything what former ProgressDlg did and mine don't. I looked around sources of Wix (not only a basic installation, but a full  develop sources, of course) to find any place which referenced ProgressDlg and I didn't find anything what could help.

Comment: Hello, I finally made a buildable version which shows a problem. I added it to github. Link is: https://github.com/CPP-programmer1975/Wix-progress-dialog . You should know it is my very first Wix project without any previous experience with making of installers, built within a week of learning.

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved it. I had to set a "Modeless" property to "yes" in my Progress dialog  element. If this property is not set to "Modeless", it waits for user input. Example:

```
<Dialog Id="ProgressDlg"
        Width="370"
        Height="270"
        Title="Progress dialog"
        Modeless="yes">
```